# PowerShell Consider Variable as String

Tags: string, variables, powershell

```
$ConfigFile = "C:\Outils\Config.ps1"
$Keys = Get-Content $ConfigFile |  Foreach {($_ -split '\s-',4)[0..2]}
$Keys = Get-Content $ConfigFile |  Foreach {($_ -split '=+',4)[0..2]}

ForEach($mot in $Keys)
{
 if($mot.StartsWith("$"))
 {
   Write-host $mot
 }
}
```

Hi, I made a script to extract the content of variables in my config files, and instead of showing the content of variable it's just show the name of variable :

```
$infographie
$journaliste
$photopro
```

my config file:

```
$infographie="\\uprlpv12\Asura$\OneVision\SORTIES\ILLUSTRATION_VERS_METHODE\INFOGRAPHIES_PROGRES"
$journaliste="C:\FTP\Journaliste"
$photopro="C:\FTP\PhotoPro"
```

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Ij you want to get the value of a variable called  *infographie* stored as a string $a='infographie' you can use :

```
Get-Variable -Name $a
```

Comment: Workkkkkkkkkks, Thank You,

Comment: An important note: value passed to the Name parameter for get-variable should not include a leading $ (i.e, $a='$infographie' will not do what you want).  Just mentioning this since the config file has the dollar signs.